# Improvised weapons and proficiency

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, proficiency, attack-roll, improvised-weaponry

I would like to know if I utilize “use an object” on an acid vial or  alchemist’s fire and they are treated as improvised weapons with the respective range attack up to 20 feet, can I add my proficiency bonus to my attack rolls with those items?

Evidently, tavern brawler feat allows the character become proficient with improvised weapons. This would work obviously.

- proficiency bonus + Dex modifier for attack rolls with that improvised weapon.

Although, I want to argue that vials and flasks are similar to Actual weapons of martial weapons category like the net or simple weapons category like darts and slings. This would allow my character to add the proficiency bonus to attack rolls as if the flasks or vials were similar to those weapon characteristics or properties in terms of ranged attacks and almost the same range. He/she is proficient in both simple and martial weapons.

I want to assume that vials and flasks can resemble darts, slings, and nets, so I can gain that proficiency bonus. In the end, it also depends on my DM’s discretion.

In similarities, a table leg can be familiarized as a club. In that case, I would be able to use the proficiency bonus as if a character is proficient and familiar with simple weapons.

I haven’t found anything on vials and flasks being recognized as darts, slings, and nets.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You mention the Tavern Brawler feat, but it sounds like you are trying to get the effect (proficiency) without taking the feat?

Comment: So your question would be something along the lines of "Are vials and flasks similar enough to any simple weapons to be considered proficient with them?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Resembling a weapon is entirely up to the DM.

From the [rules for improvised weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons):

> At the DM's option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.

So it is up to the DM to determine if vials and flasks bear sufficient resemblance to darts or nets. No other guidance is given.

#### I have ruled no.

I have ruled on this in the past and ruled that no, vials of acid do not bear sufficient resemblance to darts, nets, or javelins. I have in real life thrown darts, nets, javelins, and glass bottles - each is a very different skill; so in game I do not allow players to add their proficiency bonus to attacks made to throw vials of acid.

I would also be wary of giving out the benefits of a feat for free - what you're asking for here is really a function of the Tavern Brawler feat.

Comment: Thanks! I need assurance on this topic ! Very helpful insight! 

I mentioned tavern brawler because it seems to be the feasible route to gain proficiency with Improvised weapons.